# I got different output when using 2 different compilers

Tags: c, quicksort

I have a code that make me confused. So, I made a source code that will do some partition (exactly like quicksort) and on the left and right of pivot will be sorted. But, my problem is, when I submitted it to the online judge, it gives me wrong answer (but on my code, I already tried it, it gives exactly what the output should be). This is my source code :

```
#include "stdio.h"

int partition(int arr[],int left, int right);
void swap(int *a, int *b);
void quickSort(int arr[],int left, int right);

int main()
{
    int sizeArr,arr[1005], pv;
    scanf("%d",&sizeArr); getchar();

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeArr; i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]); getchar();
    }

    pv = partition(arr,0,sizeArr);
    quickSort(arr,0,pv);
    quickSort(arr,pv + 1, sizeArr);

    printf("%d",arr[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < sizeArr; i++) printf(" %d",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

int partition(int arr[],int left, int right){
    int pv = left;
    if(left < right){
        pv = left;
        int l = left;
        int r = right + 1;
        do{
            do l++; while(arr[l] < arr[pv]);
            do r--; while(arr[r] > arr[pv]);
            if (l < r) swap(&arr[l],&arr[r]);
        } while(l < r);
        swap(&arr[pv],&arr[r]);
        return arr[pv];
    }
}

void quickSort(int arr[],int left, int right){
    if(left < right){
        int pv = left;
        int l = left;
        int r = right + 1;
        do{
            do l++; while(arr[l] < arr[pv]);
            do r--; while(arr[r] > arr[pv]);
            if (l < r) swap(&arr[l],&arr[r]);
        } while(l < r);
        swap(&arr[pv],&arr[r]);
        quickSort(arr, left, r - 1);
        quickSort(arr, r + 1, right);
    }
}

void swap(int *a, int *b){
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

After my investigation, my compiler was GCC 4.9.2 32-Bit Release, but the online judge is using GCC 4.9.2 64-Bit Release. How can I solve my problem?

Input

```
5
4 5 3 7 2
```

Output on GCC 4.9.2 64-Bit release :

```
0 2 3 4 5
```

Output on GCC 4.9.2 32-Bit release :

```
2 3 4 5 7
```

Comment: There could be some undefined behavior lurking in your code somewhere that allows for ambiguous result.

Comment: @cid Yes it is, the one that make me confused how the output be different when using 2 different compilers? how can I solve this problem?

Comment: loops like `do l++; while(arr[l] < arr[pv]);` might run aut of array bounds invoking UB

Comment: Your function `partition()` does not return a value in all cases.

Comment: UB means everything can happen. Turn on compiler warnings and you'll know where the issue is right away

Comment: @phuclv - There is a good chance that the cause is UB as described by Ingo in his comment.  If that is the case I do not think compiler warning would occur.   But a debugging session with break points could help.

Comment: @ryyker no, failed to return a proper value in all code paths is a simple thing that all decent compilers will warn you about

Comment: `partition` should return an index, not an array element.

Comment: It's very unclear why first partition the array and then sort the two parts (without using `partition`).

Comment: Time for you to start compiling properly with `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`. In this case the missing `-Wall` hides the bug.

Comment: @phuclv - You were right.  CLANG pointed right to it with compiler set to ALL warnings.

Comment: @iMax you don't know what code the online judge compiled to: and you certainly *don't know what the test cases will be*. The one you are given is just an example to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

when `left >= right`, function will not return a value: (see suggestion in comment at bottom.)

```
int partition(int arr[],int left, int right){
    if(left < right){
        int pv = left;
        int l = left;
        int r = right + 1;
        do{
            do l++; while(arr[l] < arr[pv]);
            do r--; while(arr[r] > arr[pv]);
            if (l < r) swap(&arr[l],&arr[r]);
        } while(l < r);
        swap(&arr[pv],&arr[r]);
        return arr[pv];
    }
    // add a return statement here to remove all ambiguity
    // then test the return of this statement before using its results
}
```

...Which will lead to unexpected results, or possibly *[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)*  in this calling statement:

```
pv = partition(arr,0,sizeArr);//pv may not be set properly here...
quickSort(arr,0,pv);//if pv is not set properly, unexpected
                    //results can occur here.
```

As mentioned in the comments, compiler warnings can help you to catch these things early.  Set your compiler warnings to the strictest level.  For example
I set my compiler warning to ALL (CLANG), and it showed me this in your code:
[image]